# Can you check if two variables have the same type in Elm?

Tags: functional-programming, typeclass, elm

I want to write

```
Check: a -> b -> Bool
```

Where check returns true if a and b have the same type. Is this possible in elm?

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick, but what about `check: a -> a -> Bool; check a b = true`? If `a` and `b` have the same type, this will return `true` and if they don't, this will fail to compile. (I'm having trouble imagining a situation where you end up with a value whose type you don't know in a language with as strict a type system as Elm.)

Comment: You need GADTs for dynamic type equality checks, and I don't think Elm has those.

Comment: @gsg Doesn't GADTs pattner match against the tags of their constructors, not the underlying type? So the OP could match against `True`/`False` but not against `Bool`, provided boolean were implemented as a sum type in Elm.

Comment: @ftor: with GADTs you can have an representation for types on which you can pattern match. In this sense you _can_ match against `Bool`. Furthermore, GADT pattern matching provides type equalities so you can use this pattern matching to satisfy the type checker that something is of type `Bool`, dynamically. The machinery for all this is a bit complicated, and Elm doesn't have it (unless GADTs were added recently?), so the OP seems to be out of luck.

Answer (score 11):

You are missing a fundamental point in **strictly typed** languages, such as Elm. It is not possible to arrive at a situation where types need to be checked *dynamically*, because the compiler forces you to work with identical types while you are developing because of its *static* type checking.

Comparison of dynamic vs statically typed languages evokes huge programmer emotion. Decide for yourself what you prefer.